# How do I connect two elements in a linguistic examples via lines when using expex package?

Tags: linguistics, expex, parselines

I am using expex package to list linguistic examples, but have no idea about how to connect two elements within an example via lines.

Here's the initial code for the example:

```
**\pex
\a \rightcomment{crossing NP-Num.CL links}*NP\textsubscript{k}...NP\textsubscript{m}...Num-CL\textsubscript{k}...Num-CL\textsubscript{m}
\a \rightcomment{nested NP-Num.CL links}*NP\textsubscript{k}...NP\textsubscript{m}...Num-CL\textsubscript{m}...Num-CL\textsubscript{k}
\a \rightcomment{non-crossing/nested NP-Num.CL links}*NP\textsubscript{k}...NP\textsubscript{k}...Num-CL\textsubscript{m}...Num-CL\textsubscript{m}
\xe**
```

I also attached a screenshot that shows what lines I need.[image]

Comment: Use the `movement-arrows` package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. For future questions please do not post fragments of code. Instead turn the fragment into a complete compilable document that people can play with.

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. While using movement-arrows package, my TexShop shows that `movement-arrows.sty' not found. How should I fix this?

Comment: You need a current year TeXLive updated, since the package is quite new. If you can't update to the current year MacTeX, then you will have to install the package manually from [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/movement-arrows). If you do this it should be installed in:  `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/movement-arrows`  but I would recommend just updating your whole distribution since that way you'll get updates to the package automatically.